# How to get an icon associated with specific Account from AccountManager.getAccounts()

Tags: java, android, icons, user-accounts, accountmanager

There is an icon displayed in account settings for each account. For Google account there is one icon, for Facebook another.

Is there a way of getting this icon from the code in application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I solved it:

```
    private Drawable getIconForAccount(Account account, AccountManager manager) {
        AuthenticatorDescription[] descriptions =  manager.getAuthenticatorTypes();
        PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
        for (AuthenticatorDescription description: descriptions) {
            if (description.type.equals(account.type)) {
                return pm.getDrawable(description.packageName, description.iconId, null); 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The `ContactManager` sample has an example on how to get the icon for an account if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get small icon??

Comment: hey got it..use `smallIconId` insted of `iconId`