# Contact source icon from Contacts Provider

Tags: android

In the Android Contacts application, non-local contacts have a icon to indicate the source of the contact (e.g. Google contact, Skype contact). My application is showing all the contacts and I want to show the source using the same icon. However, I don't want to maintain my own set of icons. Is it possible to get this icon from the ContactProvider. I found the API that provided the [contact a/c info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.SyncColumns.html) but don't see the constant for icon. Is it possible to get this icon. If yes then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the way to do this. Here are the steps:

- Get Contact's [ACCOUN_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#ACCOUNT_TYPE).
- Add [GET_ACCOUNTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) permission in the manifest file.
- Get the [Account](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html) using [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) [getAccountsByType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)). Note that this returns an array but we can assume that all of them have the same icon (for the same account type), so just fetch the first one.
- Now get the icon for the account using the [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657096/how-to-get-an-icon-associated-with-specific-account-from-accountmanager-getaccou)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [CONTACT_STATUS_ICON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactStatusColumns.html#CONTACT_STATUS_ICON) might be what you're looking for. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I tried using this field. It is always null for all my contacts.